# Unable to use costura fody with asp.net

Tags: fody-costura

I have problems using costura fody with the latest build and standard small web services ( both asmx and wcf )

To test this. I build a simple asp.net project (hello world). I am using 2 simple class libraries as references.

```
[WebMethod] public string HelloWorld() 
{ 
   Class1 c1 = new Class1(); 
   Class2 c2 = new Class2(); 
   return c1.GetData() + c2.GetData(); 
}
```

This is working fine without Costura/Fody

Adding latest version of Costura/Fody from github:

When I run it now I get compile errors saying DotNetCompilerPlatform missing :

> type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
>   warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>

The DotNetCompilerPlatform dll is part of the embedded dll's.

Why is this ?

Trying the same with a WCF service I encounter a simular problem.

Regards

Comment: Welcome. Could you describe what problems are you having?

Comment: Adding latest version of Costura/Fody: When I run it now I get :

Linje 12:   <system.codedom>
Linje 13:     <compilers>
Linje 14:       <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs"
Linje 15:         type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
Linje 16:         warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>

Comment: Why is this ? What am I missing here ?

Comment: Try add all this to your question, use the formatting tools to make the code more legible (aka. make the code looks like code). This type of comments are just for short clarifications